# How does the temperature affect the diameter of a brass ball, and the hole it has to go through (hole is in a thin steel plate)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, volume

A brass ball has a diameter of 25.232 mm and a hole in a thin steel plate has a diameter of 25.220 mm at 21.5 C. Both the steel and the brass ball have the same temperature all the time. At which temperature does the brass ball go through the hole?

[image]

First I calculated the volume of the brass ball

$V=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\pi\cdot\left(12.616\right)^3=8411.1165379117\ mm^3$

Then the volume needed for the brass ball to go through the hole.

$V=\frac{4}{3}\cdot \pi \cdot \left(12.61\right)^3 =8398.1225396174\ mm^3$

$V=\left(57\cdot\frac{10^{-6}}{C}\right)\cdot\left(8411...mm^3\right)\cdot\left(x\right)=8398mm^3$ (1)

$x=17516.8C$ (1)

But then I realised that the diameter of the hole gets also effected by the temperature, and now I'm stuck. Does anyone know how to solve this kind of a problem?

edit (1): added calculations that I've calculated

Comment: Have you learned about thermal expansion?

Comment: Yes, I have, and calculated it, but I dumped it since the hole in the steel will also get bigger/smaller and I have no clue on how to calculate it. @ChetMiller

Comment: Can you calculate how much the circumference of the hole increases linearly?

Comment: The radius of the hole will get bigger by the same amount that a rod of length equal to the radius would get bigger. You can use that to calculate how much the hole will get bigger for a given temperature

Comment: No, I can't. @ChetMiller

Comment: Each little segment around the circumference would increase in length in proportion to $1+\alpha \Delta T$, so the new circumference would be $2\pi R_0(1+\alpha \Delta T)$

Comment: Could you write a step-by-step solution, it would be super helpful? @ChetMiller

Comment: In my judgment, you’ve had adequate hints.

Comment: But, I don't understand it. @ChetMiller

Comment: I forgot to the part where I calculate the thermal expansion, could you take a look? @ChetMiller

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of thermal expansion describes the increase in a diameter or a circumference, since one is a linear function of the other.  You don't need to work with the volume.